# No se actualiza la tabla despues de filtrar un elemento

Tags: java

Buenas noches estoy tratando de realizar un filtro a una tabla, con el codigo que tengo ya filtra la tabla, el problema es que cuando quiero borrar o editar un elemento filtrado, no funciona bien la tabla no se actualiza y por ende borra otro elemento o edita otro. "este es el codigo que uso para filtrar"

```java
 private void txtFiltroKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
        
       DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel)TablaRefacciones.getModel();
         txtFiltro.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
               String cadena = (txtFiltro.getText()).toUpperCase();
               txtFiltro.setText(cadena);
               repaint();
               tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(txtFiltro.getText(),3));
            }
         });
         tr = new TableRowSorter( TablaRefacciones.getModel());
         TablaRefacciones.setRowSorter(tr);
        
}
```

Comment: Puedes colocar el código como texto por favor?

Comment: DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel)TablaRefacciones.getModel();
         txtFiltro.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
               String cadena = (txtFiltro.getText()).toUpperCase();
       txtFiltro.setText(cadena);
       repaint();
        tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(txtFiltro.getText(),3));
            }
         
         
         });
         tr = new TableRowSorter( TablaRefacciones.getModel());
         TablaRefacciones.setRowSorter(tr);

Comment: No, edita tu pregunta y coloca el código en lugar de la imágen, así es ilegible.

Comment: listo @Alex, crees que puedas ayudarme a dar una solución? no se si entiendas el problema que tengo, si lo redacte bien.